# localstorage if and else not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to create a styleswitcher for my website. I've successfully created a dropdown menu and save it on the localstorage..Now, I'm trying to use the localstorage info to `alert()` via if and else but it isn't working. Here is the code:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var item = window.localStorage.getItem('active_style');
    $('select[name=active_style]').val(item);

    $('select[name=active_style]').change(function() {
       window.localStorage.setItem('active_style', $(this).val());
    });

    if (item == "dark") {
        alert("WORKS");
    };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="active_style" id="lol" class="dropdownselect" >
    <option value="">Default</option>   
    <option value="Dark" selected="selected">Dark</option>
</select>
```

I've no idea why it isnt working. Please help.

Comment: the value is case-sensitive, so you should have `== "Dark"` to match your `<option value="Dark"`

Answer (score 2):

This is happens, because you are stored `Dark` and you compare it with `dark`. See the case-sensitive thing. The first `D` is uppercase.

Comment: There is one thing that *really* annoys me on SO. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: Nope. Please tell me.

Comment: Users that either don't read the comments, or add an answer based on  a previous comment :) If that is the only error this question should be closed as a typo.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Although answers should not be _answered_ as comments. If the one commenting posts the answer without making the question close-able then someone else must.

Comment: @Jonast92: Because the answer is just a typo... that does not justify an answer :P

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It's an answer if it solves the problem. Of course it's not as intensive or _cool_ like long answers to complex problems but a solution is a solution which qualifies as an answer, no matter how simple it is. Anyway, don't comment something if you'll get annoyed by someone who actually answers it with the same answer, who knows, maybe he didn't even see your comment :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The different was 30 seconds. I've copied the code into my netbeans, check the console, then fixed it, write it as an answer, formated it. Sorry, if I did not see that comment.

Comment: @Jonast92: There is a good reason for the "close as it as a simple typographical error" option. Note to lolka_bolka: the difference was nearly two minutes, but who's counting :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own early comment as an answer to silence the complainers who feel this typo actually deserves an answer :)

"The value is case-sensitive, so you should have `== "Dark"` to match your `<option value="Dark"`"